# Get Facebook status and replies for those status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler

I am trying to get facebook status and replies for those status, so what I didn't find anything other than Status messages: [a link] https://graph.facebook.com/367501354973 (A status message from Bret). Looks like this require userid but how can I get user id's of my friends. If I get my friends can I get the status of friends of my friends. I have been searching every possible place to find an answer on getting facebook status along with the replies but so for no luck. It would be great if there is a webcrawler for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Check this
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

You can also use below facebook Graph API Explorer tool to test
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=580490479

You can get your friend's ID by below
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=

You can get updated of Your friends by 
https://graph.facebook.com/580490479/feed

and for Posting check below
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

--- Samir